# How to create a macro for string containing ,<Status, tinyint,>

Tags: c#, vb.net, regex, macros

I just read little bit about macro and was trying to create the one in .net
I was able to do very small operations since I don't know much about vb.net and regular expressions.

I want to create a properties and variable declaration for the below code.
What will be the regular expression to parse this string. So that I can get all the components to create a property from this.

```
,<Status, tinyint,>
```

I am trying to create macro that can parse above string into

```
private byte _Status;
public byte Status { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why would you want your macro to create an automatic property *and* a separate field?

Comment: @Jon: I just come to know about macro. I am trying to explore more and more things on it. There is no reason as of now but just looking forward to make my coding faster. So thought to minimize my work by using this. Moreover about automatic property i am just doing an experiments on it and will thnk about it where i can use it in live project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use something along the lines of

```
(?<val>[A-Za-z]+)
```

to grab your values, where 'val' is the name of a matching group. Don't have a compiler infront of me to work out the exact syntax. Have a play on [gskinner](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) to get it right